# How can I create a function that appends an empty array?

Tags: arrays, swift, function

```
// I am attempting to answer the following question:
```

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

```
//Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.



// function creating both integers, max number, and filtering 
func sumOfMultiples(x: Int, y: Int, n: Int)  {
    var numberList: [Int] = []
    for i in 0..<y {
        if x < n && y < n && x % n == 0 || y % n == 0 {
            return numberList.append(i)
        }
    
    } 
}


sumOfMultiples(x: 3, y: 5, n: 1000)
```

Comment: Don't use return `return`. And where do you sum?

Comment: Solving [PE #1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)?

Comment: Is it in the requirements to record a list of all the numbers?  If not you can just keep adding to a 'sum' every time round the loop and return it

Comment: Could you elaborate on where and why you need to append an empty array? Worst case you can declare an array of type [Any], and then just append([])

Comment: @MartinR Yes!!! I'm currently working through exercism.io

Comment: @Larme thank you Larme! I understand now that I didn't set up a function with an explicit return value.

Comment: @AndyP You are exactly right - I understand now why I don't need to use an array. Thank you!

Comment: @Cheetaiean Thank you for clarifying! I realize I just need to use an Int. Thanks for showing me an alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what the code you have is trying to achieve, but it can't work for several reasons.

Here is some working code that achieves this:

```
func sumOfMultiples(x: Int, y: Int, n: Int)->Int {
    var returnValue: Int = 0

    if x < n && y < n {
        for i in 0..<n {
            if i % x == 0 || i % y == 0 {
                returnValue += i
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue
}

print(sumOfMultiples(x: 3, y: 5, n: 1000))
```

Output:

```
233168
```

The issues in the code you posted are:

- The function has no return type (it's a void function). I added `->Int` to return an integer.
- The function stores a list of integers - why?  If the sum only is required, store the value in an `Int` and return it.
- The `for` loop is looping up until `y`.  Actually, it should be `n`.
- The comparison for `x` and `y` being below `n` is executed in each loop iteration.  No need to waste resources - do it before the loop.
- The modulo operation (`x % n` and `y % n`) is invalid for the use case.  It's actually `i % x` and `i % y` because you are testing `i` in each case.

Comment: The checks  for  `x < n && y < n` are not needed. There is also a dedicated method `isMultiple(of:)` to check for divisors.

Comment: Martin, you didn't help the OP come up with a solution, you gave them a completed solution. This sounds like a homework assignment, and if you just provide a complete answer the OP won't learn.

Answer (score 0):

If the result you want is the sum of all the numbers:

```
func sumOfMultiples(x: Int, y: Int, n: Int) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    for number in 1..<n {
        if number % x == 0 || number % y == 0 {
            result += number
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

If the result you want is an array with all the numbers:

```
func arrayOfMultiples(x: Int, y: Int, n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] =  []
    for number in 1..<n {
        if number % x == 0 || number % y == 0 {
            result.append(number)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

You could also use a custom range as a parameter, like this:

```
func sumOfMultiples(x: Int, y: Int, n: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    for number in n {         //Notice the change from 1..<n to just n
...
}

func arrayOfMultiples(x: Int, y: Int, n: ClosedRange<Int>) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] =  []
    for number in n {         //Notice the change from 1..<n to just n
...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
sumOfMultiples(x: 3, y: 5, n: 10...20)
//Result is 75

arrayOfMultiples(x: 3, y: 5, n: 10...20)
//Result is [10, 12, 15, 18, 20]
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!!!! I really appreciate you taking the time to show me how to solve this using both an array and with sum. You have also just introduced me to custom ranges - thank you!